# Custom page template displays the archive template

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom page template named "page-news.php" and it contains

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: News
*/
get_header();

?>
test
<?php 
wp_footer();
get_footer();
?>
```

and I then create a page and set the template to "News" but when I view the page, it does not display the contents on the page-news.php custom page template, instead it display the archive.php contents (I have test it, whatever I put unto the archive.php contents, it display on the page that I hook unto the page-news.php custom page template). Any ideas, help please? I'm running WP 4.7.2.

Answer (score -1):

Please rename the file name i.e. from 'page-news.php' to 'news.php' or any other name but don't add 'page-' in the file name & then select the template again for the page in the admin backend.

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: it is clearly stated on the wordpress doc that if you gonna use a custom page template you must named it page-{slug}.php.

Comment: please try it for once. may be it can help you.

Comment: As there are hierarchies in the wordpress,if news will be a slug of any page/category, so it will output the code of archive.php page or page.php page according to the hierarchy.